# Xbox 360 with 3 red lights

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

My Xbox 360 is dead. I've been googling for a week, asking on the official Xbox forums, and calling to the Xbox support phone, but **I still don't know if I need to repair the console or only the power supply** (they're both still under the warranty period).

These are the symptoms:

- Front ring: **3 red lights**, blinking.
- Power supply LED: with the console off, it's orange (as it should be). When I turn on the console, it becomes green... but just for a second, and then goes back to **orange**. It does not blink.
- No console activity at all: there is no video, the disk tray doesn't work, the fans are not running...

I've followed the steps shown [here](http://forums.xbox-scene.com/index.php?showtopic=484726) to determine the *secondary error code*. In my case, **0001**, which apparently means "possible power supply problem". That's the same diagnostic given by the online troubleshooting wizard on the Xbox support page. However, when I called the official support phone, they told me that what needs to be repaired is my console, not the power supply.

Who's wrong? The call center guy, or the Internet?

Has anybody had these exact symptoms? How did you solve it? Was it the console or the power supply?

By the way, it's a Xbox 360 Elite (september 2009), just in case it makes any difference.

Comment: Have you tried a "known good" power supply brick?  You can probably either borrow a friend's, or go someplace with a good return policy and buy one, test it with your console, and then return it as a check.

Comment: I wish I could try that, but I don't know anybody who could lend me his power brick... and I don't know of any local store selling these. I could buy a new console and then return it, but that would be "a little" expensive just for a test :)

Comment: Darn.  I don't know how it is where you live, but most used game shops and big box stores with video game departments will generally sell replacement adapters such as this.  Return policies tend to make it cost nothing if you return within a window specified by the retailer.

Comment: It's called the Red Ring of Death (RRoD), and has been covered [at least once](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18/can-i-fix-the-xbox-360-red-ring-of-death-myself).

Comment: @agent86 I didn't know, I never saw replacement units at sale... I'll ask at some stores.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro yes, I know how it's called, and I know there are a billion web sites and forum posts talking about it, including a few ones here. However, there are also several causes that can lead to RRoD (power supply, motherboard, any other faulty component, etc.). That's why I asked if somebody else, with the EXACT SAME SYMPTOMS, could share his experience with me and tell me if it was the power supply or the console.

Comment: You can always take your unit to a store and ask if they could try to attach it to another power supply. But why bother if you have warranty anyways, just send it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last!!! I borrowed a power supply from a friend, and I've verified that the console works fine. So, after all **it was a power supply failure**, not a problem with the console itself. So glad that I trusted the Internet and not the Microsoft phone support guy... :P

Answer (score -1):

Fix 3 Red Lights are not realy big deal if you watch this video and get the all video series here : [Fix 3 Red Lights on XBOX 360](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beq4BP71kHw)

Answer (score -3):

Your console needs to be replaced. Power supply is fine. Just call support or go to support.xbox.com and raise a service request. There is no way to repair it ourselves, unless you are happy with no warranty and have idea of soldering and hardware repair in general.

Comment: Actually, I just verified that the console is fine, the power supply needs to be replaced :)